# Posting label text along with the array checkbox values

Tags: php, javascript

I have following checkbox arrays in html form

```
<label><input name="columns[]" type="checkbox" value="pname" />Property Name</label>
<label><input name="columns[]" type="checkbox" value="2000" />Price</label>
<label><input name="columns[]" type="checkbox" value="New Road" />Location</label>
<label><input name="columns[]" type="checkbox" value="Joe Smith" />Owner</label>
```

there are about 30 such checkboxes.

All i want to do is sending the text along with its value of the checked box while form is posted. Lets say if i checked first checkbox, I want to send  `pname` along with text `Property Name`. There can be several solutions for this, but don't know which one will be easier one.

The one I thought is. In submit page iterating through the loop of checkbox array, create another array and Push the text manually to this new array.

Or other option I have thought is, in value attribute I will send text with value like this `pname^Property Name` and in submit page i iterate through loop, explode the value and put them to respective arrays.

Is there any alternative solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: You could `<input name="columns['Property Name']" type="checkbox" value="pname" />`.

Comment: @JaredFarrish, do this work if I have text `Sale/Rent` ??

Comment: It's a valid [PHP array key](http://codepad.org/QoLq62kN).

Comment: You could also `<input name="columns[pname]" type="checkbox" value="Property Name" />`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<label><input name="columns['Property Name']" type="checkbox" value="pname" />Property Name</label>
<label><input name="columns['Price']" type="checkbox" value="2000" />Price</label>
<label><input name="columns['Location']" type="checkbox" value="New Road" />Location</label>
<label><input name="columns['Owner']" type="checkbox" value="Joe Smith" />Owner</label>
```

**PHP**

```
$columns = $_GET["columns"]; // or $_POST

echo $columns["Property Name"] ;   // pname
echo $columns["Price"] ;           // 2000
echo $columns["Location"] ;        // New Orad
echo $columns["Owner"] ;           // Joe Smith
```

Comment: unfortunately I have texts like `Sales/Rent`, `Area In Sq. Ft`,`Semi-furnished`, which will yield the "Disallowed key" error

Comment: you might have to create a mapping between sanitize input name to your field name. e.g.:  "Sales/Rent" => "sales_rent"

Comment: I just replaced illegal characters with space so that `Sales/Rent` becomes `Sales Rent`, still got error `Disallowed Key Characters` error. WHile i do `print_r($_POST["columns"])`

Comment: @Neverever—in that case the OP can just map from the value to whatever other value they want.

Comment: @LoVeSmItH have a look `config/config.php`, `$config['permitted_uri_chars']` tells you what characters are valid

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this

```
$posted_columns = implode(',',$_POST['columns']);
print_r($posted_columns);
```

but your code should be like this

```
<label><input name="columns['Property Name']" type="checkbox" value="pname" />Property Name</label>
```

Comment: unfortunately that will not work as I wanted I guess, It will just gives a checkbox value, not the label text

Comment: Sorry it should be name="columns['Property Name']"